# How can I fix the lag for share screening between Mountain Lion and Lion?

Tags: macos

I screenshare with my friend everyday. It was working well until he updated to Mountain Lion. Now there is a significant delay regardless of network activity. Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: This may be unrelated.  There was a recent update for the Apple Remote Desktop Client. Have you installed that update?  Has your friend?

Comment: Yes, we both installed all latest updates